# python connect to hive, get an error

Tags: python-3.x, hive

I use `pyhive` to connect to `hive(3.5)`. Code is as follows.

```
from pyhive import hive

conn=hive.connect(host='localhost',port=10000,database='database')
```

the second line makes an error as follows:

> File
>   "/Users/chenjiahui/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py",
>   line 217, in readI32
>       buff = self.trans.readAll(4)
>
> AttributeError: 'TSaslClientTransport' object has no attribute
>   'readAll'

How can I solve this problem？

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your database username and password ?

You can try like this

```
hive.connect(host='localhost',
               port=10000,
               authMechanism="PLAIN",
               user='yourusername',
               password='yourpassword',
               database='yourdatabase')
```

Comment: There is not database username and password.

Comment: and my friend can connect successfully using the same python version, but I failed in my computer.